# Flutter Google ML-KIT align text correctly

Tags: flutter

[image]I'm using google ML kit to make a Flutter receipt scanner app. I'm able to scan and display text correctly however when it comes to displaying the scanned text it all get's messed up.(See attached picture).

Here's my code for performing the scan.

```
void _recognizTexts() async {
  // Creating an InputImage object using the image path
  final inputImage = InputImage.fromFilePath(_imagePath);
  // Retrieving the RecognisedText from the InputImage
  final text = await _textDetector.processImage(inputImage);
  // Finding text String(s)
  for (TextBlock block in text.blocks) {
    for (TextLine line in block.lines) {
       print('text: ${line.text}');
    }
  }
```

[[image: Output text][1]]